# 401 invalid credentials with oauth 2.0 google + api ,throwing apiServiceException..why so..?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-plus

This is how I code to get authenticate user with google and displaying basic things.

Getting error while authenticate user with google

> Error : invalid credentials with oauth 2.0 google + api ,throwing apiServiceException

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiPlusService.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiOauth2Service.php';

session_start();

$client = new apiClient();

$client->setApplicationName('demo');
$client->setClientId('asd6354egfdgtdewd');
$client->setClientSecret('-ooRVhB5nbdsfisfgf7s6fsfsfj');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://demo.com');
$client->setDeveloperKey('HGFHJVhjb894rbbvjhdfjdsvkbdvdv');

$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
                             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'));

$plus   = new apiPlusService($client);
$oauth2 = new apiOauth2Service($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            # FIXME Is exit() missing?
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken())
{
        $me   = $plus->people->get('me');
        $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

            $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

            $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
        $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public',$optParams);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    } else {

           $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

}
```

Comment: can you test all configs in google playground of oauth... https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: will u pls guide me to test in oauth playground..???wat to do in 2nd step..????

Comment: its quite simple actually. just select the service you want to play with from left side and prace authorize app button and then its wizrd like...

Comment: but what to write in referesh token and access token ..???

Comment: code.google.com/p/oauth-plugin/wiki/RequestToken

Comment: i am not getting what does the doc explaining.will pls guide me step by step in oauthplayground..????

Comment: in 1st step i hv selected d scopes which are i want...but in second step what to do after clicking on authorization code for tokens button..?? from where to get refresh token and access token ..??

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand in specific?

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/02399bt13

Comment: @hkre did u see the above error image..???

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function `setAccessToken($token)` right before calling `$plus->people->get('me')` and `$user = $oauth2->userinfo->get()`.